# Network issues in my lan network

Tags: networking, router

I have a internal network 172.16.x.x and my server having a static ip 172.16.x.x and all other client machines have DHCP pool.And i natted my network with public ip 119.139.x.2 and my server with another public IP 119.139.x.3.Is there any possibility to access the server with public IP of server for internal users with 172.16.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your router supports loopback NAT (also called "hairpin NAT").